# Groupby Pandas dataframe and plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a Pandas dataframe and wish to plot from a specific column by group. The goal is to have a **separate graph** for each org (like the image below).

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmWDG.png)

What is the **most efficient** way to accomplish this?

Source excerpt:

```
date                      time1           time2                time3     org                                                              
2017-11-16 02:14:20       36.46           20.42                16.04     abc
2017-11-21 08:39:15       40.12           10.18                29.94     abc
2017-11-06 08:21:08       33.00            0.00                33.00     bcd
2017-10-30 14:29:03       47.50           10.33                37.17     bcd
2017-11-09 07:51:48       31.92            1.92                30.00     efg
2017-11-07 08:53:05       33.00            1.04                31.96     efg
```

Attempted Code:

```
# load data
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

# identify unique values in org col
org_group = sorted(df['org'].unique())

# set date as index for plot
df = df.set_index('date')
df.head()

for i in range(len(org_group)):
    # select specific org value from df
    df_group = df[df.org == org_group[i]]

    # display plot
    df_plot = df_group.resample('W').agg('median').plot(title="Median Times for "+org_group[i])
    plt.show()

    # iterate
    i = i+1
```

Comment: What are you plotting?

Comment: please define - what is a `"data point"`...

Comment: Also, please provide some of the code you have tried.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ uploaded a photo. Separate graphs by org.

Comment: Your code is doing a LOT of things that your question has mentioned nothing about. As it stands, this is a little unclear.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ah I was calling the wrong df, not the grouped one. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is named `df`

```
df = df[df.org == 'abc']
```

will filter it for `abc`

To get a list of unique items in `org` column use `df.org.unique().tolist()`

Then you can iterate through the list and get a separate dataframe for each of the orgs